Best way to repeat <slot> content in a custom element
I have a custom element that shows a list, where each item is also a component.
One team builds the library components - they don't know what each record should look like. A different team uses them in lots of different places (one might be a list to be carousels of product photos, another might need each record to be a link, inputs or action menus) - they know how to render each item but not the repeater.
The library components might be doing a lot of work - say a virtual scroller that's paginating data based in visibility observers.
Something like (pseudo code):
<my-list .ids=[1,2,3]>
  #shadow-root (open)
    <ul>
      <li><my-item id=1></my-item></li>
      <li><my-item id=2></my-item></li>
      <li><my-item id=3></my-item></li>
    </ul>
</my-list>

I want to add something inside the nested element, using light-DOM and a <slot>. I realise I can do this explicitly with named slots, something like...
<my-list .ids=[1,2,3]>
  <button slot="item1" @click=${this.remove(1)}>remove</button>
  <button slot="item2" @click=${this.remove(1)}>remove</button>
  <button slot="item3" @click=${this.remove(1)}0>remove</button>
</my-list>

Rendering to
<my-list>
  #shadow-root (open)
    <ul>
      <li><my-item id=1>
        <slot name="item1">
          <button @click=${this.remove(1)}>remove</button>
        </slot>
      </my-item></li>...

But I don't know how many items I will have in my list and everything needs looping twice.
Ideally I want to do something like:
<my-list .ids=[large array]>
  <button @click=${e=>this.remove(e.target.someProperty)}>remove</button>
</my-list>

And have that button appear in every <my-item>'s <slot> content.
But that will fill one default slot, it won't repeat.
In <my-list> I can listen for the slotchange event and when it fires check (e.target as HTMLSlotElement).assignedElements() and copy the contents to each repeated child slot, but this seems to get very nasty with events and properties.
For instance, an implementation might look like this:
<my-list 
    .getRowData=${() => /* set the data property here */}>
    <item-template .data=${ignored}>
        This control is actually a template that will be cloned for each row
    </item-template>
    <header-row slot="header">
        As this is a regular slot, it just works as expected
    </header-row>
</my-list>

Users have to implement complex data functions and understand how some slotted content is picked up as templates while others work as expected.
The other practice would be to pass lots of extra information to <my-list> so that when it's repeating the shadow DOM elements it can render the <slot> content for each one, but that basically serialises down (through properties) what should be rendering information.
An example of this one might be:
<my-list 
    .renderRow=${() => 
        // output the content to populate
        // for instance if we use Lit
        html`
        <span>row text</span>
        <input @change=${e => this.expectComponentOrParent?}>`
    }
    @change=${does this handle the events from inputs?}>
</my-list>

Whether the events work depends on whether the component is populating the calling code's light DOM... it probably shouldn't, but if it populates it's own shadow DOM the uncomposed event won't reach the calling code.
It's not that these can't be solved, it's that every solution involves some pretty painful and extremely easy to get confused/wrong compromises.
Is there a way to have light DOM repeated in <slot> content in the shadow DOM?
If not, are there any emergent best practices on how to do this kind of repeated content?

Its the "repeat" every Framework implements, peak at their source-code? In Svelte its the EachBlock But I didn't go down that rabbithole, documentation of Svelte code $%k$!

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman no, it's not a problem with repeating code. You can use whatever repeat you want in the component - I want to render something inside that repeated content that I configure outside. For instance having a <data-table> that does all the sorting, row rendering and pagination, but I want to configure a per-row drop down menu that might be different on different uses of the table. I can use a named slot for not-repeated content (so <data-table><div slot="header">...) but I want to repeat it (so <data-table><row-menu slot="each-row">...)

You have a shadowRoot on <my-list> Then what is the value of having a shadowRoot on <my-item> (which you don't show in above code) Only to have <slot> elements in <my-item>?? Since you already have a shadowRoot it can't be styling for the (component) end-user (unless you also add plenty of exportparts.
Its already your component, so you can create DOM anywhere. Maybe create a more elaborate proof of concept... In general I use shadowRoots at the top of a DOM tree or down at the bottom/leafs ( eg. icons) Any shadowRoots in between cause work (and headaches)

Thinking out of the box; what I did with <pie-chart> and <slice> is the same concept: There can be N slices inside a chart, and the <pie-chart> Web Component has to deal with N <slice>  see: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/what-web-technologies-are-required-to-draw-a-pie-chart-in-2021-spoiler-alert-a-standard-web-component-will-do-1j56 (not code you can 1:1 copy to a table.. too much SVG) The concept is that a Web Component processes its lightDOM. Then also read: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-component-developers-do-not-connect-with-the-connectedcallback-yet-4jo7

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman oh it's pseudo-code, I just missed the shadow roots on the custom elements. The key bit is that <my-list><div class="local-class">... is in the light DOM of the calling code, there shouldn't need to be a .local-class CSS definition inside the shadow DOM for <my-list> (or <my-item>, or any other nested element). You can create/access DOM content inside a custom element, but I'm specifically asking about slots in the shadow DOM.

But what is the why of using slots? Slots are great when you want to fill DOM with USER!! DOM content. Your user isn't creating DOM but "wants" to trigger DOM creation with something like .ids=[large array]. So you the developer are creating DOM. Slots have no advantage. Its like a kitchen drawer (slots).. what you want is a (slot) robot that puts the knives and forks in the drawer... but you are standing next to the robot handing the knives and forks to the robot. What advantage does the (slotting) robot have that you do not have?

The robot can create content in a SLOT (and the SLOT)... You can create anything you want. Without CSS/DOM issues, because you already have a shadowRoot higher up in the DOM tree.

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman imagine you're WebAwesome or someone like that making components for others to use, and you want to make a <virtual-scroll> control. It handles all the visibility observer loading and dynamic pagination stuff, but you want to make it as easy as possible for your customers to use it. One wants to virtual scroll a product list (each with a photo carousel and a buy menu), another wants a customer list with call and email options. Your <virtual-scroll> is rendering the list, but each item in the list is rendered by someone else.

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman every solution seems either closely coupled (like events that pass dynamic slot names up) or idiosyncratic (like a property on the control that takes a render function) - these are fine if you don't want a reusable control, or you want your entire product dev team to understand the internals of your repeating control, or you want to re-implement it each time. I want a reusable control even the junior devs on my team can use.

Start building instead of designing, failure is success in progress. "pass dynamic slot names up"... why is everyone only passing data? You can also pass the slot element itself, or pass a method(reference) on the caller to the callee.. which gives you direct access to the caller this scope

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman I already have a working solution in production - it just is horrible for junior devs to use (because it's weird and idiosyncratic and you need to do extra stuff in JS to make it work). I'm trying to ask about better ways, if there are any.

Show the horriblenes in code, then people can comment
